# iTunes wishlist on ipad

Tags: itunes, ios, itunes-store

Is there a way to view your iTunes wishlist on an iPad? I checked at the bottom of the iTunes app but I couldn't find it there.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no way.
http://imore.com/wish-list

Comment: Why was this down voted?